# fastest MD5 Implementation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, md5

There are many MD5 JavaScript implementations out there. 
Does anybody know which one is the most advanced, most bugfixed and fastest?

I need it for [this](http://www.bruechner.de/md5file/js/) tool.

Comment: Why do you need a "fast" MD5 implementation?

Comment: There are some different implementations out there, some are broken. And I need it for large binary files.

Comment: I needed it for this tool: http://www.bruechner.de/md5file/js/

Comment: @AnthonyWJones is there a need for any other type of md5 function? It's not like a "slow" md5 function really serves any purpose.. does it?

Comment: I think about splitting one of the common implementations for web workers, to get even a faster solution. Or does this not matter? Since the processors can not be faster as they are?

Comment: @LeeOlayvar The slower a cryptography function is, the longer it would take to bruteforce a given hash using that function.

Comment: @MathiasBynens Yes but by design, md5 is a fast hash. That is to say, it's designed to consume large amounts of data and output a hash very, very fast. This is essentially the last thing you want for storing secure data such as passwords/etc, and is better suited/designed for **identifying** data. Slow hashes on the otherhand, are designed to be slow from the ground up. Brute forcing a slow hash, with a large work value, is not an easy task. As such, slow hashes are ideal for passwords. MD5 is bad for passwords in many (most?) cases. I'm not an expert in this field, so take this with salt. :)

Comment: Yes, but as there is a [spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1321.txt) that mandates what an MD5 hash looks like, it does not matter whether you compute it quickly or slowly. The end result is the same and will be equally as difficult / easy to bruteforce. So it *does* make sense to use the fastest implementation.

Comment: @MathiasBynens Why would somebody use javascript to bruteforce an md5 hash?

Comment: @CameronMartin I didn’t say anything about JavaScript.

Answer (score 206, accepted):

I've heard Joseph's Myers implementation is quite fast. Additionally, he has a [lengthy article](https://web.archive.org/web/20170425230948/http://www.webreference.com:80/programming/javascript/jkm3/index.html) on Javascript optimization describing what he learned while writing his implementation. It's a good read for anyone interested in performant javascript.

[http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/jkm3/](https://web.archive.org/web/20170425230948/http://www.webreference.com:80/programming/javascript/jkm3/index.html)

His MD5 implementation can be found [here](http://www.myersdaily.org/joseph/javascript/md5-text.html)

Comment: A demonstration of this md5 library can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/v28gq/

Comment: Is Joseph's Myers still the fastest implementation out there?

Comment: What is the licence for Myers' code? He doesn't indicate that it is licenced (or not) on his website as far as I can tell.

Comment: It bothers me that this implementation creates a bunch of global functions, so I wrapped the whole thing in a closure, made each function a variable and assigned the md5 function to the window object. This is obviously assuming there is a window object, but it will keep all of the supporting functions private. I'm not sure how ( if at all ) this will effect performance, but it should be much safer for use in large applications. https://gist.github.com/jhoff/7680711

Comment: Agree with jhoff. It also bothers me that this implementation fails jshint miserably, has incorrect indentation and throws errors in strict mode. Aside from the extra hour cleaning up the mess, this implementation performs well

Comment: @jhoff Your Gist has been forked and improved a couple times, I also think that the `var add32` on line 185 should be just `add32` so I found the best fork I could and updated it to this new version:

https://gist.github.com/MichaelPote/3f0cefaaa9578d7e30be

Comment: provind a link without copy pasting code is often a bad idea. Links go dead

Answer (score 90):

I would suggest you use CryptoJS in this case.

Basically CryptoJS is a growing collection of standard and secure cryptographic algorithms implemented in JavaScript using best practices and patterns. They are fast, and they have a consistent and simple interface.

So if you want to calculate the MD5 hash of your password string then do as follows:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/md5.js"></script>
<script>
    var passhash = CryptoJS.MD5(password).toString();

    $.post(
      'includes/login.php', 
      { user: username, pass: passhash },
      onLogin, 
      'json' );
</script>
```

So this script will post the hash of your password string to the server.

For further info and support on other hash calculating algorithms you can visit:

http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/

Comment: You should not be using md5 for passwords.

Comment: Looks like this will be orphaned before long, still on "google code". No one maintaining?

Comment: @LukasLiesis
MD5 for passwords + server nonce or salt is perfectly fine, just like digest authentication is still secure, provided you also protect against basic auth MTM downgrade attacks client side, but that is aside the point.

Passwords like the code above should have a server provided nonce to  concatenate with the resultant MD5 hash and re-MD5 that to send to the server for authentication, this prevents collisions attacks.

Comment: @Motes md5 is fast algorithm it's easy to regenerate database for brute force or just decoding if passwords would be leaked with salts.

Comment: @LukasLiesis Not if the server nonce is unique to each client session. MD5 may be too fast for you to be comfortable or something emotional like that, but you will never hack a Digest authentication server by replay or collision attacks.

Comment: @LukasLiesis Here is a Authorization header from a request to my server, if MD5 is so vulnerable, you should be able to hack into win7.motes.camp/UploadToMotes.html and upload me a surprise: Authorization : Digest username="Motes", realm="Motes", nonce="UUsMgOInBQA=e3b79ef7fa18f626eca3f9e0843aa2faf529a05f", uri="/icon/image2.gif", algorithm=MD5, response="f48072416cfd028339cc3bcc1b8b024f", qop=auth, nc=00000015, cnonce="24d0a1aa18b7a0a3"

Comment: md5 is fast and if someone cracks your site and your db & code is leaked you can always generate db with hashes and decode passwords. Give me your live database with 10M users & code. I will have fun with that and post on the internet my decoded results. Cheers.

Comment: The link leads to a 404 Page now

Comment: [MD5 is more risky than slower hash functions, for passwords, please avoid.](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure#answer-19908)

Answer (score 60):

### My favorite md5

This one is 42 lines long, fits in 120 characters horizontally, and looks good. Is it fast? Well - it's fast enough and it's approximately the same as all other JS implementations. But it's just oddly satisfying to look at all those nicely aligned columns. Don't deny.

> **NOTE: input should be a string**
> In practice, numbers and arrays will work (since 2023 feb 20, thank you Andreas Riedmüller), but objects will always return the same md5 every time. To support objects, add a line with JSON.stringify; I didn't because md5 is designed for strings.

```js
//  Formatted version of a popular md5 implementation
//  Original copyright (c) Paul Johnston & Greg Holt.
//  The function itself is now 42 lines long.

function md5(inputString) {
    var hc="0123456789abcdef";
    function rh(n) {var j,s="";for(j=0;j<=3;j++) s+=hc.charAt((n>>(j*8+4))&0x0F)+hc.charAt((n>>(j*8))&0x0F);return s;}
    function ad(x,y) {var l=(x&0xFFFF)+(y&0xFFFF);var m=(x>>16)+(y>>16)+(l>>16);return (m<<16)|(l&0xFFFF);}
    function rl(n,c)            {return (n<<c)|(n>>>(32-c));}
    function cm(q,a,b,x,s,t)    {return ad(rl(ad(ad(a,q),ad(x,t)),s),b);}
    function ff(a,b,c,d,x,s,t)  {return cm((b&c)|((~b)&d),a,b,x,s,t);}
    function gg(a,b,c,d,x,s,t)  {return cm((b&d)|(c&(~d)),a,b,x,s,t);}
    function hh(a,b,c,d,x,s,t)  {return cm(b^c^d,a,b,x,s,t);}
    function ii(a,b,c,d,x,s,t)  {return cm(c^(b|(~d)),a,b,x,s,t);}
    function sb(x) {
        var i;var nblk=((x.length+8)>>6)+1;var blks=new Array(nblk*16);for(i=0;i<nblk*16;i++) blks[i]=0;
        for(i=0;i<x.length;i++) blks[i>>2]|=x.charCodeAt(i)<<((i%4)*8);
        blks[i>>2]|=0x80<<((i%4)*8);blks[nblk*16-2]=x.length*8;return blks;
    }
    var i,x=sb(""+inputString),a=1732584193,b=-271733879,c=-1732584194,d=271733878,olda,oldb,oldc,oldd;
    for(i=0;i<x.length;i+=16) {olda=a;oldb=b;oldc=c;oldd=d;
        a=ff(a,b,c,d,x[i+ 0], 7, -680876936);d=ff(d,a,b,c,x[i+ 1],12, -389564586);c=ff(c,d,a,b,x[i+ 2],17,  606105819);
        b=ff(b,c,d,a,x[i+ 3],22,-1044525330);a=ff(a,b,c,d,x[i+ 4], 7, -176418897);d=ff(d,a,b,c,x[i+ 5],12, 1200080426);
        c=ff(c,d,a,b,x[i+ 6],17,-1473231341);b=ff(b,c,d,a,x[i+ 7],22,  -45705983);a=ff(a,b,c,d,x[i+ 8], 7, 1770035416);
        d=ff(d,a,b,c,x[i+ 9],12,-1958414417);c=ff(c,d,a,b,x[i+10],17,     -42063);b=ff(b,c,d,a,x[i+11],22,-1990404162);
        a=ff(a,b,c,d,x[i+12], 7, 1804603682);d=ff(d,a,b,c,x[i+13],12,  -40341101);c=ff(c,d,a,b,x[i+14],17,-1502002290);
        b=ff(b,c,d,a,x[i+15],22, 1236535329);a=gg(a,b,c,d,x[i+ 1], 5, -165796510);d=gg(d,a,b,c,x[i+ 6], 9,-1069501632);
        c=gg(c,d,a,b,x[i+11],14,  643717713);b=gg(b,c,d,a,x[i+ 0],20, -373897302);a=gg(a,b,c,d,x[i+ 5], 5, -701558691);
        d=gg(d,a,b,c,x[i+10], 9,   38016083);c=gg(c,d,a,b,x[i+15],14, -660478335);b=gg(b,c,d,a,x[i+ 4],20, -405537848);
        a=gg(a,b,c,d,x[i+ 9], 5,  568446438);d=gg(d,a,b,c,x[i+14], 9,-1019803690);c=gg(c,d,a,b,x[i+ 3],14, -187363961);
        b=gg(b,c,d,a,x[i+ 8],20, 1163531501);a=gg(a,b,c,d,x[i+13], 5,-1444681467);d=gg(d,a,b,c,x[i+ 2], 9,  -51403784);
        c=gg(c,d,a,b,x[i+ 7],14, 1735328473);b=gg(b,c,d,a,x[i+12],20,-1926607734);a=hh(a,b,c,d,x[i+ 5], 4,    -378558);
        d=hh(d,a,b,c,x[i+ 8],11,-2022574463);c=hh(c,d,a,b,x[i+11],16, 1839030562);b=hh(b,c,d,a,x[i+14],23,  -35309556);
        a=hh(a,b,c,d,x[i+ 1], 4,-1530992060);d=hh(d,a,b,c,x[i+ 4],11, 1272893353);c=hh(c,d,a,b,x[i+ 7],16, -155497632);
        b=hh(b,c,d,a,x[i+10],23,-1094730640);a=hh(a,b,c,d,x[i+13], 4,  681279174);d=hh(d,a,b,c,x[i+ 0],11, -358537222);
        c=hh(c,d,a,b,x[i+ 3],16, -722521979);b=hh(b,c,d,a,x[i+ 6],23,   76029189);a=hh(a,b,c,d,x[i+ 9], 4, -640364487);
        d=hh(d,a,b,c,x[i+12],11, -421815835);c=hh(c,d,a,b,x[i+15],16,  530742520);b=hh(b,c,d,a,x[i+ 2],23, -995338651);
        a=ii(a,b,c,d,x[i+ 0], 6, -198630844);d=ii(d,a,b,c,x[i+ 7],10, 1126891415);c=ii(c,d,a,b,x[i+14],15,-1416354905);
        b=ii(b,c,d,a,x[i+ 5],21,  -57434055);a=ii(a,b,c,d,x[i+12], 6, 1700485571);d=ii(d,a,b,c,x[i+ 3],10,-1894986606);
        c=ii(c,d,a,b,x[i+10],15,   -1051523);b=ii(b,c,d,a,x[i+ 1],21,-2054922799);a=ii(a,b,c,d,x[i+ 8], 6, 1873313359);
        d=ii(d,a,b,c,x[i+15],10,  -30611744);c=ii(c,d,a,b,x[i+ 6],15,-1560198380);b=ii(b,c,d,a,x[i+13],21, 1309151649);
        a=ii(a,b,c,d,x[i+ 4], 6, -145523070);d=ii(d,a,b,c,x[i+11],10,-1120210379);c=ii(c,d,a,b,x[i+ 2],15,  718787259);
        b=ii(b,c,d,a,x[i+ 9],21, -343485551);a=ad(a,olda);b=ad(b,oldb);c=ad(c,oldc);d=ad(d,oldd);
    }
    return rh(a)+rh(b)+rh(c)+rh(d);
}
```

Another absolutely irrelevant fact: it's 4000 bytes long. It may seem pointless but it feels good to just *know*. You look at it and you know. You belong to the secret club of Those Who Just Know. Life will never be the same. Trust me.

Also, thank you **Paul Johnston** and **Greg Holt**.
And Douglas Adams, for all the fish.

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bs5-starter-q4f3ib)

Comment: @dkelner Cool. I'd like to copy/paste your function to use in my app. Please could you grant a licence

Comment: There's no need, it's absolutely free to use, it's a derived work from another free implementation. So just use it and maybe comment the authors like I did.

Comment: Hoep you don't mind but I added a [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bs5-starter-q4f3ib) link to your answer

Comment: Here's Typescript class translation, linted, with a unit test https://jsfiddle.net/y3sh/653ejsqL/2/

Comment: *3953 bytes long, including comments and whitespace.

Comment: Just a heads up: If you pass a Number you will always get the same hash no matter what number you use. Be sure to make it a string first!

Comment: @RichardDunn It depends on line breaks. I just tested again with Windows CRLFs and it's 4000

Answer (score 58):

## Node.js has built-in support

```
const crypto = require('crypto')
crypto.createHash('md5').update('hello world').digest('hex')
```

Code snippet above computes MD5 hex string for string `hello world`

The advantage of this solution is you don't need to install additional library.

I think built in solution should be the fastest. If not, we should create issue/PR for the Node.js project.

Comment: This should be higher up.

Comment: The problem is that this solution throws `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` in browser consoles so it does not really work..

Comment: @Taureon, the answer was written for Node.js. To use this feature in browser, I believe you can take advantage of webpack, to bundle the Node.js code for browser.

Comment: @TylerLiu but is there a solution that does not require webpack?

Comment: @Taureon the solution I posted is for Node.js. I am unaware of a way to make it work in browser easily.

Answer (score 38):

While selecting library it's also important to see if it supports modern frameworks such as Bower, passes jslint, supports plugin model for JQuery or module systems such as AMD/RequireJS in addition to being in active development and have more than 1 contributors. There are couple of options that satisfies some or all of these additional criteria:

- [CryptoJS](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/): This is perhaps the most expansive library where each algorithm can be used separately without adding fat in to your JS code. Plus it as encoder/decoders for UTF8, UTF16 and Base64. I maintain [github repository](https://github.com/sytelus/CryptoJS) that is registered as Bower package plus instructions on how to use it with RequireJS.
- [Spark MD5](https://github.com/satazor/SparkMD5): This is based on JKM code that other answer mentions which is also the faster implementation. However in addition, Spark implementation adds AMD support, passes jslint plus has incremental mode. It doesn't have Base64 o/p but it does have raw o/p (i.e. array of 32-bit int insead of string).
- [JQuery MD5 plugin](https://github.com/placemarker/jQuery-MD5): Very simple down to earth but doesn't seem to have raw mode.
- [JavaScript-MD5](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-MD5): Not as fancy or fast as Spark but simpler.

Example from CryptoJS:

```
//just include md5.js from the CryptoJS rollups folder
var hash = CryptoJS.MD5("Message");
console.log(hash.toString());
```

There is a performance comparison between above libraries at http://jsperf.com/md5-shootout/7. On my machine current tests (which are admittedly old) shows that if you are looking for speed Spark MD5 is your best bet (and so is plain JKM code). However if you looking for more comprehensive library then CryptoJS is your best bet although it is 79% slower than Spark MD5. However I would imagine CryptoJS would eventually achieve same speed as it is bit more active project.

Comment: The link to "jQuery MD5 plugin" leads me to a malware site. Eep!

Comment: Looks like original website for jQuery MD5 plugin got shutdown and its now redirects to generic domain seller. I've updated to plugin hosted in GitHub now.

Answer (score 27):

I really can't remember where did I get this from.. I searched everywhere on the net and the only references I find are from this post. Strange.
If anyone has infos about this implementation origin, let me know.

Or you can try this new one which is 25% faster: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74186696/236062  :D

```js
MD5 = function(e) {
    function h(a, b) {
        var c, d, e, f, g;
        e = a & 2147483648;
        f = b & 2147483648;
        c = a & 1073741824;
        d = b & 1073741824;
        g = (a & 1073741823) + (b & 1073741823);
        return c & d ? g ^ 2147483648 ^ e ^ f : c | d ? g & 1073741824 ? g ^ 3221225472 ^ e ^ f : g ^ 1073741824 ^ e ^ f : g ^ e ^ f
    }

    function k(a, b, c, d, e, f, g) {
        a = h(a, h(h(b & c | ~b & d, e), g));
        return h(a << f | a >>> 32 - f, b)
    }

    function l(a, b, c, d, e, f, g) {
        a = h(a, h(h(b & d | c & ~d, e), g));
        return h(a << f | a >>> 32 - f, b)
    }

    function m(a, b, d, c, e, f, g) {
        a = h(a, h(h(b ^ d ^ c, e), g));
        return h(a << f | a >>> 32 - f, b)
    }

    function n(a, b, d, c, e, f, g) {
        a = h(a, h(h(d ^ (b | ~c), e), g));
        return h(a << f | a >>> 32 - f, b)
    }

    function p(a) {
        var b = "",
            d = "",
            c;
        for (c = 0; 3 >= c; c++) d = a >>> 8 * c & 255, d = "0" + d.toString(16), b += d.substr(d.length - 2, 2);
        return b
    }
    var f = [],
        q, r, s, t, a, b, c, d;
    e = function(a) {
        a = a.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");
        for (var b = "", d = 0; d < a.length; d++) {
            var c = a.charCodeAt(d);
            128 > c ? b += String.fromCharCode(c) : (127 < c && 2048 > c ? b += String.fromCharCode(c >> 6 | 192) : (b += String.fromCharCode(c >> 12 | 224), b += String.fromCharCode(c >> 6 & 63 | 128)), b += String.fromCharCode(c & 63 | 128))
        }
        return b
    }(e);
    f = function(b) {
        var a, c = b.length;
        a = c + 8;
        for (var d = 16 * ((a - a % 64) / 64 + 1), e = Array(d - 1), f = 0, g = 0; g < c;) a = (g - g % 4) / 4, f = g % 4 * 8, e[a] |= b.charCodeAt(g) << f, g++;
        a = (g - g % 4) / 4;
        e[a] |= 128 << g % 4 * 8;
        e[d - 2] = c << 3;
        e[d - 1] = c >>> 29;
        return e
    }(e);
    a = 1732584193;
    b = 4023233417;
    c = 2562383102;
    d = 271733878;
    for (e = 0; e < f.length; e += 16) q = a, r = b, s = c, t = d, a = k(a, b, c, d, f[e + 0], 7, 3614090360), d = k(d, a, b, c, f[e + 1], 12, 3905402710), c = k(c, d, a, b, f[e + 2], 17, 606105819), b = k(b, c, d, a, f[e + 3], 22, 3250441966), a = k(a, b, c, d, f[e + 4], 7, 4118548399), d = k(d, a, b, c, f[e + 5], 12, 1200080426), c = k(c, d, a, b, f[e + 6], 17, 2821735955), b = k(b, c, d, a, f[e + 7], 22, 4249261313), a = k(a, b, c, d, f[e + 8], 7, 1770035416), d = k(d, a, b, c, f[e + 9], 12, 2336552879), c = k(c, d, a, b, f[e + 10], 17, 4294925233), b = k(b, c, d, a, f[e + 11], 22, 2304563134), a = k(a, b, c, d, f[e + 12], 7, 1804603682), d = k(d, a, b, c, f[e + 13], 12, 4254626195), c = k(c, d, a, b, f[e + 14], 17, 2792965006), b = k(b, c, d, a, f[e + 15], 22, 1236535329), a = l(a, b, c, d, f[e + 1], 5, 4129170786), d = l(d, a, b, c, f[e + 6], 9, 3225465664), c = l(c, d, a, b, f[e + 11], 14, 643717713), b = l(b, c, d, a, f[e + 0], 20, 3921069994), a = l(a, b, c, d, f[e + 5], 5, 3593408605), d = l(d, a, b, c, f[e + 10], 9, 38016083), c = l(c, d, a, b, f[e + 15], 14, 3634488961), b = l(b, c, d, a, f[e + 4], 20, 3889429448), a = l(a, b, c, d, f[e + 9], 5, 568446438), d = l(d, a, b, c, f[e + 14], 9, 3275163606), c = l(c, d, a, b, f[e + 3], 14, 4107603335), b = l(b, c, d, a, f[e + 8], 20, 1163531501), a = l(a, b, c, d, f[e + 13], 5, 2850285829), d = l(d, a, b, c, f[e + 2], 9, 4243563512), c = l(c, d, a, b, f[e + 7], 14, 1735328473), b = l(b, c, d, a, f[e + 12], 20, 2368359562), a = m(a, b, c, d, f[e + 5], 4, 4294588738), d = m(d, a, b, c, f[e + 8], 11, 2272392833), c = m(c, d, a, b, f[e + 11], 16, 1839030562), b = m(b, c, d, a, f[e + 14], 23, 4259657740), a = m(a, b, c, d, f[e + 1], 4, 2763975236), d = m(d, a, b, c, f[e + 4], 11, 1272893353), c = m(c, d, a, b, f[e + 7], 16, 4139469664), b = m(b, c, d, a, f[e + 10], 23, 3200236656), a = m(a, b, c, d, f[e + 13], 4, 681279174), d = m(d, a, b, c, f[e + 0], 11, 3936430074), c = m(c, d, a, b, f[e + 3], 16, 3572445317), b = m(b, c, d, a, f[e + 6], 23, 76029189), a = m(a, b, c, d, f[e + 9], 4, 3654602809), d = m(d, a, b, c, f[e + 12], 11, 3873151461), c = m(c, d, a, b, f[e + 15], 16, 530742520), b = m(b, c, d, a, f[e + 2], 23, 3299628645), a = n(a, b, c, d, f[e + 0], 6, 4096336452), d = n(d, a, b, c, f[e + 7], 10, 1126891415), c = n(c, d, a, b, f[e + 14], 15, 2878612391), b = n(b, c, d, a, f[e + 5], 21, 4237533241), a = n(a, b, c, d, f[e + 12], 6, 1700485571), d = n(d, a, b, c, f[e + 3], 10, 2399980690), c = n(c, d, a, b, f[e + 10], 15, 4293915773), b = n(b, c, d, a, f[e + 1], 21, 2240044497), a = n(a, b, c, d, f[e + 8], 6, 1873313359), d = n(d, a, b, c, f[e + 15], 10, 4264355552), c = n(c, d, a, b, f[e + 6], 15, 2734768916), b = n(b, c, d, a, f[e + 13], 21, 1309151649), a = n(a, b, c, d, f[e + 4], 6, 4149444226), d = n(d, a, b, c, f[e + 11], 10, 3174756917), c = n(c, d, a, b, f[e + 2], 15, 718787259), b = n(b, c, d, a, f[e + 9], 21, 3951481745), a = h(a, q), b = h(b, r), c = h(c, s), d = h(d, t);
    return (p(a) + p(b) + p(c) + p(d)).toLowerCase()
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="md5.value=MD5(a.value);">

<form oninput="md5.value=MD5(a.value)">Enter String:
<input type="string" id="a" name="a" value="https://www.zibri.org"></br></br>MD5:<output id="md5" name="md5" for="a"></output>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but it seems the fastest implementation is this one: myersdaily.org/joseph/javascript/jkm-md5.js

Comment: this link doesn't work myersdaily.org/joseph/javascript/jkm-md5.js

Comment: @Giggs just use google and you will find it: http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/contrib/jkm-md5.js

Comment: Thanks man. This works really efficiently. However, I'm sure if am the only one who isn' t getting this right. How do I decrypt?

Comment: @MpwanyiSamuel  yes, you are. MD5 is a hashing algorythm. you don't "decrypt it"

Comment: Thanks man. I added this to my indexed Db module to encrypt data saved in the IDB as a small privacy catch. Worked like a charm

Comment: I really can't remember where did I get this from.. I searched everywhere on the net and the only references I find are from this post. Strange.

Answer (score 27):

**As of 2020** the fastest MD5 implementation is probably written in WASM (Web Assembly).

[hash-wasm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hash-wasm) is a library that implements MD5 hash in WASM.

You can find the benchmarks [here](https://daninet.github.io/hash-wasm-benchmark/).

You can either install it with npm:

```
npm i hash-wasm
```

or just add a script tag

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hash-wasm"></script>
```

then use the `hashwasm` global variable.

**Example:**

```
async function run() {
  console.log('MD5:', await hashwasm.md5('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'));
}

run();
```

**outputs**

```
MD5: 9e107d9d372bb6826bd81d3542a419d6
```

Comment: Best answer of the question

Answer (score 12):

I found a number of articles on this subject.
They all suggested Joseph Meyers implementation.

see: http://jsperf.com/md5-shootout on some tests

in My quest for the ultimate speed i looked at this code, an i saw that it could be improved. So i created a new JS script based on the Joseph Meyers code.

see [Improved Jospeh Meyers code](http://2basix.nl/page.php?al=javascript%20fast%20md5)

Comment: why fork it, instead of just submitting your patch back to the maintainer?

Comment: @ez2 your link is not working anymore. Would you mind reposting your code? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I only need to support HTML5 browsers that support typed arrays (DataView, ArrayBuffer, etc.)
I think I took the Joseph Myers code and modified it to support passing in a Uint8Array. I did not catch all the improvements, and there are still probably some char() array artifacts that can be improved on. I needed this for adding to the PouchDB project.

```
var PouchUtils = {};
PouchUtils.Crypto = {};
(function () {
    PouchUtils.Crypto.MD5 = function (uint8Array) {
        function md5cycle(x, k) {
            var a = x[0], b = x[1], c = x[2], d = x[3];

            a = ff(a, b, c, d, k[0], 7, -680876936);
            d = ff(d, a, b, c, k[1], 12, -389564586);
            c = ff(c, d, a, b, k[2], 17, 606105819);
            b = ff(b, c, d, a, k[3], 22, -1044525330);
            a = ff(a, b, c, d, k[4], 7, -176418897);
            d = ff(d, a, b, c, k[5], 12, 1200080426);
            c = ff(c, d, a, b, k[6], 17, -1473231341);
            b = ff(b, c, d, a, k[7], 22, -45705983);
            a = ff(a, b, c, d, k[8], 7, 1770035416);
            d = ff(d, a, b, c, k[9], 12, -1958414417);
            c = ff(c, d, a, b, k[10], 17, -42063);
            b = ff(b, c, d, a, k[11], 22, -1990404162);
            a = ff(a, b, c, d, k[12], 7, 1804603682);
            d = ff(d, a, b, c, k[13], 12, -40341101);
            c = ff(c, d, a, b, k[14], 17, -1502002290);
            b = ff(b, c, d, a, k[15], 22, 1236535329);

            a = gg(a, b, c, d, k[1], 5, -165796510);
            d = gg(d, a, b, c, k[6], 9, -1069501632);
            c = gg(c, d, a, b, k[11], 14, 643717713);
            b = gg(b, c, d, a, k[0], 20, -373897302);
            a = gg(a, b, c, d, k[5], 5, -701558691);
            d = gg(d, a, b, c, k[10], 9, 38016083);
            c = gg(c, d, a, b, k[15], 14, -660478335);
            b = gg(b, c, d, a, k[4], 20, -405537848);
            a = gg(a, b, c, d, k[9], 5, 568446438);
            d = gg(d, a, b, c, k[14], 9, -1019803690);
            c = gg(c, d, a, b, k[3], 14, -187363961);
            b = gg(b, c, d, a, k[8], 20, 1163531501);
            a = gg(a, b, c, d, k[13], 5, -1444681467);
            d = gg(d, a, b, c, k[2], 9, -51403784);
            c = gg(c, d, a, b, k[7], 14, 1735328473);
            b = gg(b, c, d, a, k[12], 20, -1926607734);

            a = hh(a, b, c, d, k[5], 4, -378558);
            d = hh(d, a, b, c, k[8], 11, -2022574463);
            c = hh(c, d, a, b, k[11], 16, 1839030562);
            b = hh(b, c, d, a, k[14], 23, -35309556);
            a = hh(a, b, c, d, k[1], 4, -1530992060);
            d = hh(d, a, b, c, k[4], 11, 1272893353);
            c = hh(c, d, a, b, k[7], 16, -155497632);
            b = hh(b, c, d, a, k[10], 23, -1094730640);
            a = hh(a, b, c, d, k[13], 4, 681279174);
            d = hh(d, a, b, c, k[0], 11, -358537222);
            c = hh(c, d, a, b, k[3], 16, -722521979);
            b = hh(b, c, d, a, k[6], 23, 76029189);
            a = hh(a, b, c, d, k[9], 4, -640364487);
            d = hh(d, a, b, c, k[12], 11, -421815835);
            c = hh(c, d, a, b, k[15], 16, 530742520);
            b = hh(b, c, d, a, k[2], 23, -995338651);

            a = ii(a, b, c, d, k[0], 6, -198630844);
            d = ii(d, a, b, c, k[7], 10, 1126891415);
            c = ii(c, d, a, b, k[14], 15, -1416354905);
            b = ii(b, c, d, a, k[5], 21, -57434055);
            a = ii(a, b, c, d, k[12], 6, 1700485571);
            d = ii(d, a, b, c, k[3], 10, -1894986606);
            c = ii(c, d, a, b, k[10], 15, -1051523);
            b = ii(b, c, d, a, k[1], 21, -2054922799);
            a = ii(a, b, c, d, k[8], 6, 1873313359);
            d = ii(d, a, b, c, k[15], 10, -30611744);
            c = ii(c, d, a, b, k[6], 15, -1560198380);
            b = ii(b, c, d, a, k[13], 21, 1309151649);
            a = ii(a, b, c, d, k[4], 6, -145523070);
            d = ii(d, a, b, c, k[11], 10, -1120210379);
            c = ii(c, d, a, b, k[2], 15, 718787259);
            b = ii(b, c, d, a, k[9], 21, -343485551);

            x[0] = add32(a, x[0]);
            x[1] = add32(b, x[1]);
            x[2] = add32(c, x[2]);
            x[3] = add32(d, x[3]);

        }

        function cmn(q, a, b, x, s, t) {
            a = add32(add32(a, q), add32(x, t));
            return add32((a << s) | (a >>> (32 - s)), b);
        }

        function ff(a, b, c, d, x, s, t) {
            return cmn((b & c) | ((~b) & d), a, b, x, s, t);
        }

        function gg(a, b, c, d, x, s, t) {
            return cmn((b & d) | (c & (~d)), a, b, x, s, t);
        }

        function hh(a, b, c, d, x, s, t) {
            return cmn(b ^ c ^ d, a, b, x, s, t);
        }

        function ii(a, b, c, d, x, s, t) {
            return cmn(c ^ (b | (~d)), a, b, x, s, t);
        }

        function md51(s) {
            txt = '';
            var n = s.length,
            state = [1732584193, -271733879, -1732584194, 271733878], i;
            for (i = 64; i <= s.length; i += 64) {
                md5cycle(state, md5blk(s.subarray(i - 64, i)));
            }
            s = s.subarray(i - 64);
            var tail = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
            for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
                tail[i >> 2] |= s[i] << ((i % 4) << 3);
            tail[i >> 2] |= 0x80 << ((i % 4) << 3);
            if (i > 55) {
                md5cycle(state, tail);
                for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) tail[i] = 0;
            }
            tail[14] = n * 8;
            md5cycle(state, tail);
            return state;
        }

        /* there needs to be support for Unicode here,
         * unless we pretend that we can redefine the MD-5
         * algorithm for multi-byte characters (perhaps
         * by adding every four 16-bit characters and
         * shortening the sum to 32 bits). Otherwise
         * I suggest performing MD-5 as if every character
         * was two bytes--e.g., 0040 0025 = @%--but then
         * how will an ordinary MD-5 sum be matched?
         * There is no way to standardize text to something
         * like UTF-8 before transformation; speed cost is
         * utterly prohibitive. The JavaScript standard
         * itself needs to look at this: it should start
         * providing access to strings as preformed UTF-8
         * 8-bit unsigned value arrays.
         */
        function md5blk(s) { /* I figured global was faster.   */
            var md5blks = [], i; /* Andy King said do it this way. */
            for (i = 0; i < 64; i += 4) {
                md5blks[i >> 2] = s[i]
                + (s[i + 1] << 8)
                + (s[i + 2] << 16)
                + (s[i + 3] << 24);
            }
            return md5blks;
        }

        var hex_chr = '0123456789abcdef'.split('');

        function rhex(n) {
            var s = '', j = 0;
            for (; j < 4; j++)
                s += hex_chr[(n >> (j * 8 + 4)) & 0x0F]
                + hex_chr[(n >> (j * 8)) & 0x0F];
            return s;
        }

        function hex(x) {
            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
                x[i] = rhex(x[i]);
            return x.join('');
        }

        function md5(s) {
            return hex(md51(s));
        }

        function add32(a, b) {
            return (a + b) & 0xFFFFFFFF;
        }

        return md5(uint8Array);
    };
})();
```

Comment: I am interested in total system performance, So my demo includes xhr2 downloads and PouchDB (IDB) stores. You can try it and see the performance results at http://codepen.io/DrYSG/pen/kdzft . What I would like a MD5 algorithm person to look at is the add32() and md5blks() functions and see if they can't be sped up by binary typed arrays Uint32Array()

Comment: What `txt = ''` does actually mean?

Answer (score 6):

Currently the fastest implementation of md5 (based on Joseph Myers' code):

https://github.com/iReal/FastMD5

jsPerf comparaison: http://jsperf.com/md5-shootout/63

Comment: link is not found (404)

Answer (score 6):

I wrote tests to compare several JavaScript hash implementations, including most MD5 implementations mentioned here.
To run the tests, go to http://brillout.github.io/test-javascript-hash-implementations/ and wait a bit.

It seems that the [YaMD5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24210406/270274) implementation of [R. Hill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655769/fastest-md5-implementation-in-javascript/24210406#24210406) is the fastest.

Comment: Thank you for the great benchmark!! YaMD5 with wide characters seems slow, so I will stick to FastMD5 for generic usage.

Answer (score 4):

It bothered me that I could not find an implementation which is both fast and support Unicode strings.

So I made one which supports Unicode strings and still [shows as faster](http://jsperf.com/md5-shootout/44) (at time of writing) than the currently fastest ascii-only-strings implementations:

https://github.com/gorhill/yamd5.js

Based on Joseph Myers' code, but uses TypedArrays, plus other improvements.

Comment: Kudos to you. This is actually the only so far I found that yields the exact same hash as the md5 utility on a Unix server. Well done indeed.

Answer (score 3):

Here we go with another one which is 25% faster than my
[previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41602636/236062)
:D

```js
function MD5(r) {
var o, e, n, f = [ -680876936, -389564586, 606105819, -1044525330, -176418897, 1200080426, -1473231341, -45705983, 1770035416, -1958414417, -42063, -1990404162, 1804603682, -40341101, -1502002290, 1236535329, -165796510, -1069501632, 643717713, -373897302, -701558691, 38016083, -660478335, -405537848, 568446438, -1019803690, -187363961, 1163531501, -1444681467, -51403784, 1735328473, -1926607734, -378558, -2022574463, 1839030562, -35309556, -1530992060, 1272893353, -155497632, -1094730640, 681279174, -358537222, -722521979, 76029189, -640364487, -421815835, 530742520, -995338651, -198630844, 1126891415, -1416354905, -57434055, 1700485571, -1894986606, -1051523, -2054922799, 1873313359, -30611744, -1560198380, 1309151649, -145523070, -1120210379, 718787259, -343485551 ], t = [ o = 1732584193, e = 4023233417, ~o, ~e ], c = [], a = unescape(encodeURI(r)) + "\u0080", d = a.length;
for (r = --d / 4 + 2 | 15, c[--r] = 8 * d; ~d; ) c[d >> 2] |= a.charCodeAt(d) << 8 * d--;
for (i = a = 0; i < r; i += 16) {
    for (d = t; 64 > a; d = [ n = d[3], o + ((n = d[0] + [ o & e | ~o & n, n & o | ~n & e, o ^ e ^ n, e ^ (o | ~n) ][d = a >> 4] + f[a] + ~~c[i | 15 & [ a, 5 * a + 1, 3 * a + 5, 7 * a ][d]]) << (d = [ 7, 12, 17, 22, 5, 9, 14, 20, 4, 11, 16, 23, 6, 10, 15, 21 ][4 * d + a++ % 4]) | n >>> -d), o, e ]) o = 0 | d[1], 
    e = d[2];
    for (a = 4; a; ) t[--a] += d[a];
}
for (r = ""; 32 > a; ) r += (t[a >> 3] >> 4 * (1 ^ a++) & 15).toString(16);
return r;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="md5.value=MD5(a.value);">

<form oninput="md5.value=MD5(a.value)">Enter String:
<input type="string" id="a" name="a" value="https://www.zibri.org"></br></br>MD5:<output id="md5" name="md5" for="a"></output>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

[js-md5](https://github.com/emn178/js-md5) supports UTF-8 string, array, ArrayBuffer, AMD....

and fast. [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/md5-shootout/82)

Answer (score 2):

Here's the ES6 version of the md5 implementation by @dkellner and @Eonasdan:

```
const md5 = inputString => {
   const hc = '0123456789abcdef';
   const rh = n => {let j,s='';for(j=0;j<=3;j++) s+=hc.charAt((n>>(j*8+4))&0x0F)+hc.charAt((n>>(j*8))&0x0F);return s;}
   const ad = (x,y) => {let l=(x&0xFFFF)+(y&0xFFFF);let m=(x>>16)+(y>>16)+(l>>16);return (m<<16)|(l&0xFFFF);}
   const rl = (n,c) => (n<<c)|(n>>>(32-c));
   const cm = (q,a,b,x,s,t) => ad(rl(ad(ad(a,q),ad(x,t)),s),b);
   const ff = (a,b,c,d,x,s,t) => cm((b&c)|((~b)&d),a,b,x,s,t);
   const gg = (a,b,c,d,x,s,t) => cm((b&d)|(c&(~d)),a,b,x,s,t);
   const hh = (a,b,c,d,x,s,t) => cm(b^c^d,a,b,x,s,t);
   const ii = (a,b,c,d,x,s,t) => cm(c^(b|(~d)),a,b,x,s,t);
   const sb = x => {
      let i;const nblk=((x.length+8)>>6)+1;const blks=[];for(i=0;i<nblk*16;i++) { blks[i]=0 };
      for(i=0;i<x.length;i++) {blks[i>>2]|=x.charCodeAt(i)<<((i%4)*8);}
      blks[i>>2]|=0x80<<((i%4)*8);blks[nblk*16-2]=x.length*8;return blks;
   }
   let i,x=sb(inputString),a=1732584193,b=-271733879,c=-1732584194,d=271733878,olda,oldb,oldc,oldd;
   for(i=0;i<x.length;i+=16) {olda=a;oldb=b;oldc=c;oldd=d;
      a=ff(a,b,c,d,x[i+ 0], 7, -680876936);d=ff(d,a,b,c,x[i+ 1],12, -389564586);c=ff(c,d,a,b,x[i+ 2],17,  606105819);
      b=ff(b,c,d,a,x[i+ 3],22,-1044525330);a=ff(a,b,c,d,x[i+ 4], 7, -176418897);d=ff(d,a,b,c,x[i+ 5],12, 1200080426);
      c=ff(c,d,a,b,x[i+ 6],17,-1473231341);b=ff(b,c,d,a,x[i+ 7],22,  -45705983);a=ff(a,b,c,d,x[i+ 8], 7, 1770035416);
      d=ff(d,a,b,c,x[i+ 9],12,-1958414417);c=ff(c,d,a,b,x[i+10],17,     -42063);b=ff(b,c,d,a,x[i+11],22,-1990404162);
      a=ff(a,b,c,d,x[i+12], 7, 1804603682);d=ff(d,a,b,c,x[i+13],12,  -40341101);c=ff(c,d,a,b,x[i+14],17,-1502002290);
      b=ff(b,c,d,a,x[i+15],22, 1236535329);a=gg(a,b,c,d,x[i+ 1], 5, -165796510);d=gg(d,a,b,c,x[i+ 6], 9,-1069501632);
      c=gg(c,d,a,b,x[i+11],14,  643717713);b=gg(b,c,d,a,x[i+ 0],20, -373897302);a=gg(a,b,c,d,x[i+ 5], 5, -701558691);
      d=gg(d,a,b,c,x[i+10], 9,   38016083);c=gg(c,d,a,b,x[i+15],14, -660478335);b=gg(b,c,d,a,x[i+ 4],20, -405537848);
      a=gg(a,b,c,d,x[i+ 9], 5,  568446438);d=gg(d,a,b,c,x[i+14], 9,-1019803690);c=gg(c,d,a,b,x[i+ 3],14, -187363961);
      b=gg(b,c,d,a,x[i+ 8],20, 1163531501);a=gg(a,b,c,d,x[i+13], 5,-1444681467);d=gg(d,a,b,c,x[i+ 2], 9,  -51403784);
      c=gg(c,d,a,b,x[i+ 7],14, 1735328473);b=gg(b,c,d,a,x[i+12],20,-1926607734);a=hh(a,b,c,d,x[i+ 5], 4,    -378558);
      d=hh(d,a,b,c,x[i+ 8],11,-2022574463);c=hh(c,d,a,b,x[i+11],16, 1839030562);b=hh(b,c,d,a,x[i+14],23,  -35309556);
      a=hh(a,b,c,d,x[i+ 1], 4,-1530992060);d=hh(d,a,b,c,x[i+ 4],11, 1272893353);c=hh(c,d,a,b,x[i+ 7],16, -155497632);
      b=hh(b,c,d,a,x[i+10],23,-1094730640);a=hh(a,b,c,d,x[i+13], 4,  681279174);d=hh(d,a,b,c,x[i+ 0],11, -358537222);
      c=hh(c,d,a,b,x[i+ 3],16, -722521979);b=hh(b,c,d,a,x[i+ 6],23,   76029189);a=hh(a,b,c,d,x[i+ 9], 4, -640364487);
      d=hh(d,a,b,c,x[i+12],11, -421815835);c=hh(c,d,a,b,x[i+15],16,  530742520);b=hh(b,c,d,a,x[i+ 2],23, -995338651);
      a=ii(a,b,c,d,x[i+ 0], 6, -198630844);d=ii(d,a,b,c,x[i+ 7],10, 1126891415);c=ii(c,d,a,b,x[i+14],15,-1416354905);
      b=ii(b,c,d,a,x[i+ 5],21,  -57434055);a=ii(a,b,c,d,x[i+12], 6, 1700485571);d=ii(d,a,b,c,x[i+ 3],10,-1894986606);
      c=ii(c,d,a,b,x[i+10],15,   -1051523);b=ii(b,c,d,a,x[i+ 1],21,-2054922799);a=ii(a,b,c,d,x[i+ 8], 6, 1873313359);
      d=ii(d,a,b,c,x[i+15],10,  -30611744);c=ii(c,d,a,b,x[i+ 6],15,-1560198380);b=ii(b,c,d,a,x[i+13],21, 1309151649);
      a=ii(a,b,c,d,x[i+ 4], 6, -145523070);d=ii(d,a,b,c,x[i+11],10,-1120210379);c=ii(c,d,a,b,x[i+ 2],15,  718787259);
      b=ii(b,c,d,a,x[i+ 9],21, -343485551);a=ad(a,olda);b=ad(b,oldb);c=ad(c,oldc);d=ad(d,oldd);
   }
   return rh(a)+rh(b)+rh(c)+rh(d);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this package was useful
https://www.npmjs.com/package/pure-md5

```js
console.time('latin');
const latin = md5('hello');
console.timeEnd('latin');

console.log('Привет: ', md5('Привет'));
console.log('嘿: ', md5('嘿'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/pure-md5@latest/lib/index.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try http://phpjs.org/functions/md5/?

Unfortunately performance is limited with any emulated script, however this can render real md5 hash.  Although I would advice against using md5 for passwords, as it is a fast-rendered hash.

Answer (score 0):

Much faster hashing should be possible by calculating on graphic card (implement hashing algorithm in WebGL), as discussed there about SHA256: [Is it possible to calculate sha256 hashes in the browser using the user's video card, eg. by using WebGL or Flash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395651/is-it-possible-to-calculate-sha256-hashes-in-the-browser-using-the-users-video)

Answer (score -1):

Strongly recommend the [SparkMD5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/spark-md5), which is support many different type of data to get the md5 and with good performance in most situation. And it has the highest weekly downloads compare to other md5 libs.

Blob data for example:

```
import SparkMD5 from 'spark-md5'

export async function computeMd5(data: Blob): Promise<string> {
  const buffer = await readAsArrayBuffer(data)
  const spark = new SparkMD5.ArrayBuffer()
  spark.append(buffer)
  return spark.end()
}
```

In the Chrome v117,  better than the [js-md5](https://github.com/emn178/js-md5).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

You could also check my [md5 implementation](http://github.com/valums/V.Framework/blob/master/V.Security.js). It should be approx. the same as the other posted above. Unfortunately, the performance is limited by the inner loop which is impossible to optimize more.

Answer (score -3):

The winner for the MD5 benchmark is [Javascript-MD5](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-MD5)

Test it on https://jsben.ch/imzpt or see on
jsfiddle.net/w731ed58/

[image: Benchmark Results]

Comment: No it's not: https://jsben.ch/Cl5Lc  mine is 10% faster :P

Answer (score -4):

If the performance of your application is limited by a Javascript implementation of MD5, then you're really doing something wrong. Consider an architectural change (Hint: use MD5 less often)

Comment: Im not using MD5 in an "native" application with JS, its a online MD5 check tool: http://www.bruechner.de/md5file/js/ no need of native app for MD5 anymore ;)