# Conditions syntax help

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to include this Regex condition and activate the analytics code (if it meets the Regex condition) in a javascript function posted below.

```
if (/^[abc].*/i.test(mystring)) {

   var _gaq = _gaq || [];  
   _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-XX']); 
   _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);  
        (function() {  
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;  
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';  
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);  
        })(); 

       alert('Congrats ABC!');  
}
```

Now how can I add the code above (regex condition and the analytics) in there?
Also, please note. The portion below works perfectly at the moment.

```
function validateCoupon( form ){
    var mystring = document.getElementById('textCoupon').value; 

if( form.textCoupon.value.length )
        {
    // validate coupon
    $.get( "/include/checkItOut.php", { coupon: form.textCoupon.value }, validateShipping );
    alert('Performed the check and matched');
        }
else
{
    form.textCoupon.style.border = '';
    validateShipping( "yes" );

    alert('You Did Not Use Any Code');
}

return false;
}
```

In other words. Somehow include the Regex condition and analytics trigger to this function here.

Comment: what does "Now how can I add the code above in there?" mean?

Comment: I'm trying to include the portion if (/^abc$/i.test... in the code below without success. It might be a syntax or condition issue. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: In `if (/^abc$/i.test(mystring);) {`, remove the `;` from inside the `if()`.

Comment: (/^[abc].*/i.test(mystring)) changed it like so. It needs to check and make sure it matches ABC. Is this correct?

Comment: What do you actually want? Call the analytics code if `validateCoupon` is called? `mystring` is not included in the function below, what should it do? Matching it against the coupon code?

Comment: Thanks for noticing this Lekensteyn, I added a var at the beginning of the code function. Still does not work for me yet though. `var mystring = document.getElementById('textCoupon').value; `

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? are you trying to let google analytic know if a coupon code is successful or failed?

Comment: kjy112, if that specific coupon code meets the Regex condition, it triggers analytics. If other coupon codes are successful (outside the regex condition) it's still ok but does not need the analytics to be activated.

Comment: Your regex is not correct to match ABC. In that case it should be /^abc.*$/i - Omit the brackets, as that only matches one character

Comment: @detonate so the goal is to track coupon code enter success rate right?  why not use custom variable in google analytics?

Comment: `/^[abc].*$/i` matches any code starting with `a`, `b` or `c` (or their uppercase versions). Do you really want that? If your coupon code starts with `abc` (uppercase allowed), followed by 5 till 8 digits, use `/^abc\d{5,8}$/i`.

Comment: kjy112, this could be a good suggestion. How would I approach this if my button trigger is `<form method='post' action='process_order.php' name='cartForm' id='cartForm' onsubmit='return validateCoupon( this );'>`

Comment: Lekensteyn, just need to check for "abc" lower or uppercase, no other characters after. How would you format `/^abc\d{5,8}$/i` to accommodate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A literal comparison between the coupon code (in lower case) and `abc` using the equality operator (`==`) is enough. You should consider a server side solution, everyone can open the source and fetch the coupon code "abc" from it.

```
function validateCoupon( form ){
    var mystring = document.getElementById('textCoupon').value; 

if( form.textCoupon.value.length )
        {
    // added: Analytics
    if ( form.textCoupon.value.toLowerCase() == "abc") {
      var _gaq = _gaq || [];  
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-XX']); 
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);  
      (function() {  
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;  
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';  
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);  
      })();
    }
    // end analytics
    // validate coupon
    $.get( "/include/checkItOut.php", { coupon: form.textCoupon.value }, validateShipping );
    alert('Performed the check and matched');
        }
else
{
    form.textCoupon.style.border = '';
    validateShipping( "yes" );

    alert('You Did Not Use Any Code');
}

return false;
}
```

Comment: Once again, been caught banging my head on syntax and this now works like a charm Lekensteyn! I'm a designer, can I help you an any way in return?

Comment: Just one question though, will the analytics take action every time or only when abc is correctly answered in this answer?

Comment: @detonate: if the couponcode equals `abc` (case-insensitive), analytics will be called. Once again, this approach is *insecure*. It looks like noobish implementations of a "login system" in Javascript: `if(password=="apple")/*ACCESS GRANTED*/`. (it can be found in the source code) Even if you use some kind of hashing, the coupon code can still be brute-forced, given the fact that coupon codes are generally not that long. But, if you do not care if the coupon code is visible, this code is fine.

Comment: Good suggestion! Could probably look into MD5 or such.

Comment: It depends on your usage. If you are selling clothing and the coupon code gives you 50% discount, you probably do not want to put it on the page at all. If the code gives you a free button, it does not matter of course. For a fast Javascript implementation of MD5, look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1655769/427545). Use some salt to make table lookups and brute forcing (a bit) more difficult.

Comment: Thanks for all the help Lekensteyn!