# MD5 of an UTF16LE (without BOM and 0-Byte End) in Javascript (C# Example provided)

Tags: c#, javascript, md5

I am sitting a few days on the following problem: I need to get a MD5 Hash of a UTF16-LE encoded string in JavaScript. I have an Example how to do this in C# but do not know how to do this in JavaScript.

Example:

```
public string GetMD5Hash (string input) { 
 MD5 md5Hasher = MD5.Create(); 
 byte[] data = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(input)); 
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
 for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++) { 
  sb.Append(data[i].ToString("x2")); 
 } 
 return sb.ToString(); 
}
```

Wanted:

```
var getMD5Hash(input){
  ....
}

var t = getMD5Hash("1234567z-äbc");
console.log(t) // --> 9e224a41eeefa284df7bb0f26c2913e2
```

I hope some one can help me :-/

Comment: JavaScript uses UTF16. If you use `charCodeAt`, you'll get your bytes. And there are many implementations of MD5 in JS (see [that related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655769/fastest-md5-implementation-in-javascript))

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I testet all of the libs, but none of them provided the correct string...

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
return challenge + "-" + require('crypto').createHash('md5').update(Buffer(challenge+'-'+password, 'UTF-16LE')).digest('hex')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let md5 = require('md5');

function getMD5_UTF16LE(str){
    let bytes = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
      let code = str.charCodeAt(i);
      bytes = bytes.concat([code & 0xff, code / 256 >>> 0]);
    }
    return md5(bytes);
}
```

needs library https://www.npmjs.com/package/md5