# Generating md5/sha1/sha256 hash of downloaded file in Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, opera, chromium, opera-extension

How can I generate downloaded file's MD5/SHA1/SHA-256 using chrome  API or other way?

Comment: Maybe it will be helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655769/fastest-md5-implementation-in-javascript

Comment: I can easily make md5 hash from string. But I need md5 from downloaded file. My experience says that it is not possible only with js. If there is any way of chrome API it is possible.  @ŁukaszBendig. file_hash and String hash are different.

Comment: @Touhid  have you looked at [crypto-js](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To generate MD5/SHA1 for file you need to access the file. At this stage extensions are just like advance webapps for most browsers. Native system support is not available to extensions for security purpose. File system API(http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) is not widely available or what is available is just for experimental.

Check following:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/768287/3260012

I hope this will help you.