# Expected performance of MD5 calculation in javascript?

Tags: javascript, md5, md5sum

I am trying out calculation of MD5 using javascript and looking at 
[fastest MD5 Implementation in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655769/fastest-md5-implementation-in-javascript) post 'JKM' implementation is suppose to be one of the faster implementations. I am using SparkMD5 which is based of off JKM implementation. However the example provided https://github.com/satazor/SparkMD5/blob/master/test/readme_example.html takes about 10seconds for a 13MB file (~23 seconds with debugger) while the same file takes only 0.03seconds using `md5sum` function in linux command line. Are these results too slow for javascript implementation or is this poor performance expected?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is expected.

First, I don't think I need to tell you that JAVASCRIPT IS SLOW. Yes, even with modern JIT optimization etc. JavaScript is still slow.

To show you that it is not your JS implementation's fault, I will do some comparisons with Node.js, so that the browser DOM stuff doesn't get in the way for benchmarking.

Test file generation:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=file bs=6M count=1
```

(my server only has 512 MB of RAM and Node.js can't take anything higher than 6M)

Script:

```
//var md5 = require('crypto-js/md5')
var md5 = require('MD5')
//var md5 = require('spark-md5').hash
//var md5 = require('blueimp-md5').md5

require('fs').readFile('file', 'utf8', function(e, b) {  // Using string here to be fair for all md5 engines
  console.log(md5(b))
})
```

(you can uncomment the contestants/benchmarkees)

The result is: (file reading overhead removed)

- MD5: 5.250s - 0.072s = 5.178s
- crypto-js/md5: 4.914s - 0.072s = 4.842s
- Blueimp: 4.904s - 0.072s = 4.832s
- MD5 with Node.js binary buffer instead of string: 1.143s - 0.063s = 1.080s
- spark: 0.311s - 0.072s = 0.239s
- `md5sum`: 0.023s - 0.003s = 0.020s

So no, spark-md5 is in reality not bad at all.

When looking at the example HTML page, I saw that they are using the incremental API. So I did another benchmark:

```
var md5 = require('spark-md5')

var md5obj = new md5()
var chunkNum = 0

require('fs').createReadStream('file')
  .on('data', function (b) {
    chunkNum ++
    md5obj.append(b.toString())
  })
  .on('end', function () {
    console.log('total ' + chunkNum + ' chunks')
    console.log(md5obj.end())
  })
```

With 96 chunks, it is 0.313s.

So no, it is not the MD5 implementation's fault at all. Performance *this* poor is TBH a little surprising, but not totally impossible as well, you are running this code in a browser.

BTW, my server is a DigitalOcean VPS with SSD. The file reading overhead is about 0.072s:

```
require('fs').readFile('file', 'utf8', function() {})
```

while with native `cat` it's about 0.003s.

For MD5 with native Buffer, the overhead is about 0.063s:

```
require('fs').readFile('file', function() {})
```