# how to encrypt and decrypt ids in javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php

I am using following javascript code to pass an id to url in php. I am using codeigniter as framework. But after I submit url I should get  decrypted id to do further work in. I know there is no way to decrypt md5(). so if you have any idea to solve this problem please help me.

My javascript code is

```
function comdelete(id) {
    var result = confirm("Do you want to delete  ?");
    var myvar = "<?php echo md5(id); ?>";
    if (result) {
        window.location.href = "http://localhost/oxford/site/dcat?id=" + myvar;
    }
}
```

Comment: echo md5(id) ..? .you are using a javascript variable ,in php echo :)

Answer (score 1):

You can not combine PHP with JavaScript, if you want encrypt a variable in JavaScript the method must be [Javascript's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655769/fastest-md5-implementation-in-javascript) MD5. If you want to do it in PHP, Ajax methods should be used, then you can assign the result to the variable `myvar`