# Javascript - How to convert string to md5 in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, unix, openssl, md5

How to obtain the output of this UNIX command in pure Javascript?

```
echo -n '2147483647/s/link127.0.0.1 secret' | openssl md5 -binary | openssl base64
```

Comment: Please edit the question with a [mcve] of the code being used so far

Comment: Why don't you want to use a library and instead want to implement the MD5 algorithm by yourself?

Comment: A search for "javascript md5" leads to e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/1655769/10622916