# Marvel API returning 409 conflict "You must provide a user key"

Tags: javascript, imdb

I have looked through similar questions on here and none of the responses seemed to help as they aren't using vanilla JS. Hopefully someone here can help out. Note: also using IMDB API if that makes a difference.
Really new to APIs and hoping this is just some stupid error on my part.

```js
var searchButton = document.getElementById("searchBtn");
var navContainer = document.getElementById("navContainer");
var userInput = document.getElementById("charSearch");
var savedSearches = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("hero")) || [];
var currentSearch = savedSearches.length;
var imdbApiStart = "https://imdb-api.com/en/API/Search/"
var imdbKey = "k_zcmn64r8/";
var marvelApiStart =
  "https://gateway.marvel.com:443/v1/public/characters?apikey=";

var marvelKey = "public_key";
var marvelOtherKey = "my_private_key";
var ts = new Date().getTime();
var hash = ts +marvelKey+marvelOtherKey;
var passhash = CryptoJS.MD5(hash).toString();
console.log(passhash);

function getHeroInfo() {
  getMovieInfo(userInput.value);
  var requestUrl = marvelApiStart + marvelKey + "&hash=" + hash + "&name=" + userInput.value
  console.log(requestUrl);
  var result = fetch(requestUrl)
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
    
  return result;
}


function postHeroInfo(data) {

}


searchButton.addEventListener("click", getHeroInfo);
```

https://developer.marvel.com/docs

Comment: Is `marvelKey` your API Key? If so, immediately remove if from the post as it is sensitive data.

Comment: I don't think your URL is correct. Appending marvelApiStart and marvelKey will result in `...?nameStartsWith=382f5...`  I would think you'd want `?nameStartsWith=Thor` or similar.

Comment: @James I think it should be `http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?apikey=yourAPIKEY&nameStartsWith=...`.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier just the public api key not the private, but ive edited it anway

Comment: Looks like a typo, `marvelApiStart + marvelKey` will end up as `nameStartsWith=public_key`.  You're not identifying a parameter as a key, so the API responds as as you're seeing.  I'm voting to close as a typo.

Comment: I've tried reordering and rewording multiple times. Even our TA couldn't help figure it out. What would be the correct way of stating it if it's a typo? @Don'tPanic

Comment: @Don'tPanic even if i remove `nameStartsWith` parameter and add my `apikey=` it returns the same error

Comment: The docs page you link to doesn't explicitly show how to use the key.  But a search for "*marvel api key*" leads me [here](https://developer.marvel.com/documentation/authorization), which includes an example URL, which shows you use `apikey`. So in your code, `marvelApiStart` should be something like `"https://gateway.../characters?apikey=";`.  Then `var requestUrl = marvelApiStart + marvelKey ...` will correctly add your key in the right place in the URL. It seems like you'd want to use only one of `nameStartsWith` or `name`, right?  If so, you'll need to update that part of the URL too.

Comment: OK - edit your question to include a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so eg include the bare minimum HTML the JS references, and remove any JS that is not part of this problem (eg empty functions, the IMDB request I guess? Or is it the IMDB query that is returning the error?

Comment: @Don'tPanic IMDB request isn't returning the error its the marvel API one that is. This is the bare minimum JS already. If i remove the IMDB request it returns a different error because getMovieInfo is within the getHeroInfo function. I will add the HTML though.

Comment: There's more to it than the initial typo; I've retracted my close vote and added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of simple problems in your code:

1. You weren't passing a key (an edit has since corrected this);
2. <strike>You're not hashing your hash string.  [The docs](https://developer.marvel.com/documentation/authorization) show that `hash` needs to be an md5 of the string `timestamp + privateKey + publicKey`.  I searched for how to md5 a string in JS, and came across [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655769/fastest-md5-implementation-in-javascript) with many options.  I chose the first one, and used [the linked md5 library](https://www.myersdaily.org/joseph/javascript/md5.js).</strike> Sorry, I see you are of course hashing - you're just not using the hash you generate.  Your `requestUrl` uses `hash` instead of the `passhash` you generated.
3. You're not passing the `ts` parameter.  [The example in the docs](https://developer.marvel.com/documentation/authorization) shows you need to include that;
4. You're using both `nameStartsWith` and `name`, AFAICT you should either one or the other, not both;

Fixing those things up, here is the basic JS to make a call to the API.  The keys are fake, so the query does not work - but the error is what we should expect if we pass fake keys: `The passed API key is invalid` (click run to see it).  If you copy-paste this code, and hardcode in your keys, it should work.

```js
var marvelApiStart = "https://gateway.marvel.com:443/v1/public/characters?apikey=";
var marvelPublicKey = 'fake key';
var marvelPrivateKey = 'fake key';
var name = 'thor';
var ts = new Date().getTime();
var hash = md5(ts + marvelPrivateKey + marvelPublicKey);
var requestUrl = marvelApiStart + marvelPublicKey + "&ts=" + ts 
    + "&hash=" + hash + "&nameStartsWith=" + name;

console.log(requestUrl);

var result = fetch(requestUrl)
.then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
})
.then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.myersdaily.org/joseph/javascript/md5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did in this way:

1. add to index.html in  next script:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/crypto-js.js"></script>
```

It is for using CryptoJs which generate hash

2. I had

```
API_KEY = 'my public api key'
BASE_URL = "https://gateway.marvel.com:443/v1/public/";
PRIV_KEY = 'my private api key'
```

3. Create function for get data from api:

```
export const getDataFromAPI = async (query) => {
  try {
    let ts = new Date().getTime();
    lethash = CryptoJS.MD5(ts + PRIV_KEY + API_KEY).toString();
    const url = `${BASE_URL}${query}?ts=${ts}&apikey=${API_KEY}&hash=${hash}`;
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

query can be 'characters', 'comics', 'creators', 'events', 'series', 'stories'. Depends on endpoint