# Any .NET MD5 library (Nuget) for Blazor (WebAssembly)?

Tags: .net, hash, blazor, md5, blazor-webassembly

I know .NET has [MD5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.md5?view=net-7.0) class. However it's not available in Blazor:

[image]

I can't find any 3rd-party library maybe because it's supported in .NET so nobody makes it. Is there any alternative? (I don't need it for hashing password in case you want to know, it's for Gravatar so it must be MD5).

I know there's a workaround that is to use Javascript instead but I want to not using JS interop if possible ([fastest MD5 Implementation in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655769/fastest-md5-implementation-in-javascript))

Comment: Why not use JS interop?  People don't implement MD5 because they don't want it for anything more than light use. Browsers now have a low-level Crypto API but even that doesn't implement MD5 precisely because it's broken. You can convert one of the implementations you linked to to C# if you want.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yeah that's my current workaround. Just wonder if there is a way without going through JS interop. I guess you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question. First the code. This is not mine but I did modify it slightly to align more with the System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 class.

```cs
public static class MD5
{
    public static byte[] ComputeHash(byte[] input)
    {
        uint num = 1732584193u;
        uint num2 = 4023233417u;
        uint num3 = 2562383102u;
        uint num4 = 271733878u;
        int num5 = (56 - (input.Length + 1) % 64) % 64;
        byte[] array = new byte[input.Length + 1 + num5 + 8];
        Array.Copy(input, array, input.Length);
        array[input.Length] = 128;
        Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(input.Length * 8), 0, array, array.Length - 8, 4);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length / 64; i++)
        {
            uint[] array2 = new uint[16];
            for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
            {
                array2[j] = BitConverter.ToUInt32(array, i * 64 + j * 4);
            }

            uint num6 = num;
            uint num7 = num2;
            uint num8 = num3;
            uint num9 = num4;
            uint num10 = 0u;
            uint num11 = 0u;
            uint num12 = 0u;
            while (true)
            {
                switch (num12)
                {
                    case 0u:
                    case 1u:
                    case 2u:
                    case 3u:
                    case 4u:
                    case 5u:
                    case 6u:
                    case 7u:
                    case 8u:
                    case 9u:
                    case 10u:
                    case 11u:
                    case 12u:
                    case 13u:
                    case 14u:
                    case 15u:
                        num10 = num7 & num8 | ~num7 & num9;
                        num11 = num12;
                        goto IL_0138;
                    case 16u:
                    case 17u:
                    case 18u:
                    case 19u:
                    case 20u:
                    case 21u:
                    case 22u:
                    case 23u:
                    case 24u:
                    case 25u:
                    case 26u:
                    case 27u:
                    case 28u:
                    case 29u:
                    case 30u:
                    case 31u:
                    case 32u:
                    case 33u:
                    case 34u:
                    case 35u:
                    case 36u:
                    case 37u:
                    case 38u:
                    case 39u:
                    case 40u:
                    case 41u:
                    case 42u:
                    case 43u:
                    case 44u:
                    case 45u:
                    case 46u:
                    case 47u:
                    case 48u:
                    case 49u:
                    case 50u:
                    case 51u:
                    case 52u:
                    case 53u:
                    case 54u:
                    case 55u:
                    case 56u:
                    case 57u:
                    case 58u:
                    case 59u:
                    case 60u:
                    case 61u:
                    case 62u:
                    case 63u:
                        if (num12 >= 16 && num12 <= 31)
                        {
                            num10 = num9 & num7 | ~num9 & num8;
                            num11 = (5 * num12 + 1) % 16u;
                        }
                        else if (num12 >= 32 && num12 <= 47)
                        {
                            num10 = num7 ^ num8 ^ num9;
                            num11 = (3 * num12 + 5) % 16u;
                        }
                        else if (num12 >= 48)
                        {
                            num10 = num8 ^ (num7 | ~num9);
                            num11 = 7 * num12 % 16u;
                        }

                        goto IL_0138;
                }

                break;
            IL_0138:
                uint num13 = num9;
                num9 = num8;
                num8 = num7;
                num7 += leftRotate(num6 + num10 + K[num12] + array2[num11], s[num12]);
                num6 = num13;
                num12++;
            }

            num += num6;
            num2 += num7;
            num3 += num8;
            num4 += num9;
        }
        var hashBytes = new byte[16];
        BitConverter.GetBytes(num).CopyTo(hashBytes, 0);
        BitConverter.GetBytes(num2).CopyTo(hashBytes, 4);
        BitConverter.GetBytes(num3).CopyTo(hashBytes, 8);
        BitConverter.GetBytes(num4).CopyTo(hashBytes, 12);
        return hashBytes;
    }
    public static string ComputeHashString(byte[] input) => string.Join("", ComputeHash(input).Select(o => o.ToString("x2")));

    private static int[] s = new int[64]
    {
        7, 12, 17, 22, 7, 12, 17, 22, 7, 12,
        17, 22, 7, 12, 17, 22, 5, 9, 14, 20,
        5, 9, 14, 20, 5, 9, 14, 20, 5, 9,
        14, 20, 4, 11, 16, 23, 4, 11, 16, 23,
        4, 11, 16, 23, 4, 11, 16, 23, 6, 10,
        15, 21, 6, 10, 15, 21, 6, 10, 15, 21,
        6, 10, 15, 21
    };

    private static uint[] K = new uint[64]
    {
        3614090360u, 3905402710u, 606105819u, 3250441966u, 4118548399u, 1200080426u, 2821735955u, 4249261313u, 1770035416u, 2336552879u,
        4294925233u, 2304563134u, 1804603682u, 4254626195u, 2792965006u, 1236535329u, 4129170786u, 3225465664u, 643717713u, 3921069994u,
        3593408605u, 38016083u, 3634488961u, 3889429448u, 568446438u, 3275163606u, 4107603335u, 1163531501u, 2850285829u, 4243563512u,
        1735328473u, 2368359562u, 4294588738u, 2272392833u, 1839030562u, 4259657740u, 2763975236u, 1272893353u, 4139469664u, 3200236656u,
        681279174u, 3936430074u, 3572445317u, 76029189u, 3654602809u, 3873151461u, 530742520u, 3299628645u, 4096336452u, 1126891415u,
        2878612391u, 4237533241u, 1700485571u, 2399980690u, 4293915773u, 2240044497u, 1873313359u, 4264355552u, 2734768916u, 1309151649u,
        4149444226u, 3174756917u, 718787259u, 3951481745u
    };

    private static uint leftRotate(uint x, int c)
    {
        return x << c | x >> 32 - c;
    }
}
```

Example use that should return the same output as the System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 version.

```cs
var hashBytes = MD5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("apples"));
```

Test I ran to compare the two MD5 methods. Used a .Net 8 console app so System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 would be available for the test.

```cs
var testStringBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("apples");

// This MD5 (pure C#)
var applesMD51 = MD5.ComputeHash(testStringBytes);
var applesMD51String = string.Join("", applesMD51.Select(o => o.ToString("x2")));
Console.WriteLine(applesMD51String);
// output: "daeccf0ad3c1fc8c8015205c332f5b42"

// System.Security.Cryptography.MD5
using var x = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
var applesMD52 = x.ComputeHash(testStringBytes);
var applesMD52String = string.Join("", applesMD52.Select(o => o.ToString("x2")));
Console.WriteLine(applesMD52String);
// output: "daeccf0ad3c1fc8c8015205c332f5b42"
```

That code was found in a popular open source Blazor UI framework [Radzen.Blazor](https://github.com/radzenhq/radzen-blazor/blob/fcbbd53dd89d1e11915fb03689f350117a7cd445/Radzen.Blazor/Common.cs#L2742). If you are using Radzen, it is Radzen.MD5.

I did find it interesting that the System.Security.Cryptography classes SHA256 and SHA512 work in Blazor WASM but its MD5 class does not. Probably because they want to retire it but I can see uses for backwards compatibility with older stuff.